# postgres extract JSON column key and values to separate columns

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table that has a column that was created by

```
json_object_agg(eventid,date_now_range) eventids_range
```

this what the data looks like stored in the table

```
{ "527813" : 184, "525947" : 133, "529957" : 178, "531490" : 143 }
```

I want to select this record and have the key and value be its own record

so this

```
select eventids_range from special_event_conflicts
```

would return something like this

```
col a     col b
527813    184
525947    133
529957    178
531490    143
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
select k.cola, v.colb
from mytable t
cross join lateral json_object_keys(t.eventids_range) as k(cola)
cross join lateral json_extract_path_text(t.eventids_range, k.cola) v(colb)
```

This works by first extracting the keys from the object using `json_object_keys()`, and then accessing the corresponding values with `json_extract_path_text()`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=10bed061f27dc8774abb1fc8d223f54f)**:

```
cola   | colb
:----- | :---
527813 | 184 
525947 | 133 
529957 | 178 
531490 | 143
```

Another - probably better - solution is to use `json_each()`:

```
select x.cola, x.colb
from mytable t
cross join lateral json_each(t.eventids_range) as x(cola, colb)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=bb65c6a870a3aa355ce4c6e1cf361cb5)**

Comment: that was nifty, thanks. I also just found out about the json_each function

Comment: @ziggy: ah yes, `json_each()` seems better - I added it to my answer.